# How do you download a specific release of Android source code (e.g. Android 2.2)

Tags: android, git, android-2.2-froyo

I've never used git before, but I'd like to download the android source code as I'm getting a crash in the 2.2 emulator and I'd like to see exactly where in the android source code it's crashing (so I can file a better bug report).

**Edit** A decent answer would include instructions on using git to download a specific repository. I'm on windows, but have installed Msysgit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure it's right, but I've done the following (in msysgit):

git clone git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/frameworks/base.git;h=refs/heads/froyo-release

Edit: I now notice that there are two tags - froyo & froyo-release. I'm not sure which one to ues, so I'm downloading them both. Can anyone tell me what the differences are?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you've found out, the Android code is not stored in only one git repository. Instead they use a python script called repo to coordinate across many repositories. Rabas has the link to Google's instructions.

I've gotten that script to run under Windows using Cygwin.  Remember to add the "-b froyo" to the repo init command.

(I don't know the difference between the tags. The repo script obscures most of that; it just deals in branch names.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [this](http://source.android.com/source/download.html) page?

When you do repo init, you must specify manifest, and if you want specific branch, after manifest you must add **-b eclair** for example.

Comment: pretty obvious that he hasn't

Answer (score 0):

the froyo branch is a working development branch

if you want a stable release get android-2.2.2_r1

Answer (score 0):

You can find out what branches are available using git:

```
mkdir /tmp/zug
pushd /tmp/zug
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest.git
cd manifest
git branch -a | sed -n '/^  r/s,.*/,,p'|sort -u|column
popd
rm -rf /tmp/zug
```

Produces something much like this:

```
android-1.6_r1          android-2.1_r1          android-2.2.3_r2        android-2.3.4_r0.9      froyo
android-1.6_r1.1        android-2.1_r2          android-2.2_r1          android-2.3.4_r1        gingerbread
android-1.6_r1.2        android-2.1_r2.1p       android-2.2_r1.1        android-2.3.5_r1        gingerbread-release
android-1.6_r1.3        android-2.1_r2.1p2      android-2.2_r1.2        android-2.3.6_r0.9      ics-mr0
android-1.6_r1.4        android-2.1_r2.1s       android-2.2_r1.3        android-2.3.6_r1        master
android-1.6_r1.5        android-2.2.1_r1        android-2.3.1_r1        android-2.3.7_r1        tradefed
android-1.6_r2          android-2.2.1_r2        android-2.3.2_r1        android-2.3_r1
android-2.0.1_r1        android-2.2.2_r1        android-2.3.3_r1        android-4.0.1_r1
android-2.0_r1          android-2.2.3_r1        android-2.3.3_r1.1      android-4.0.1_r1.2
```

Comment: look at the `git ls-remote` command, you don't need to clone.